# Non Linear Optimization in R with nloptr vs Excel

Tags: r, excel, optimization, nlopt

I can't seem to find an answer for my particular problem. I'm trying to minimize the *mean absolute error* between a real value vector and a linear combination of models as follows:

```
library(nloptr)

df <- data.frame(
  real = c(24.2418, 21.7374, 7.203, 115.0233, 16.632, 5.4644, 27.8917, 0.5904, 0.633, 105.3656, 110.0564, 122.9399, 23.0418, 4.2186, 109.5453), 
  m_1 = c(17.7790979854662, 32.93639375, 6.94294375000066, 98.909065625, 80.1068562499999, 11.656556250002, 39.868921875, 0.859157480988586, 0.612625482376216, 112.580383416359, 151.896765176957, 155.81521460987, 7.3257, 4.1268, 41.5711703205879), 
  m_2 = c(25.5062900474607, 32.7709877317137, 6.94317649489279, 98.898593448344, 80.1114267521597, 11.6563450007055, 39.8691722409057, 0.907260912997819, 0.602795676399197, 114.183526809465, 139.51052151724, 149.993624420536, 6.85002142907728, 4.66668862149305, 70.7527906311631), 
  m_3 = c(27.1495912199999, 40.2339353399999, 7.10339542, 87.1444967133334, 58.4563384933332, 11.1378198366666, 37.6030141333333, 0.852288459999999, 0.681724560000002, 100.101136186666, 118.536525109999, 136.923264319999, 5.64763034333333, 4.8659515, 70.12675835), 
  m_4 = c(25.511590625, 32.9363937499999, 7.00050769504031, 98.3660974929738, 80.10685625, 11.65655625, 39.868921875, 0.665580984791989, 0.498756215272925, 85.791042265746, 135.619508469251, 140.946144588455, 5.05824305930683, 3.25333636845094, 22.0908752674237), 
  m_5 = c(25.6118152340655, 34.5646719234769, 6.82416840383483, 91.5582383465651, 84.4603847826215, 11.3405620277701, 40.7906062254877, 0.908706704665592, 0.602817399156822, 114.326905157898, 139.595783699511, 150.046375909198, 6.8511793011574, 4.6622942290559, 56.2753212961812), 
  m_6 = c(21.9868574376585, 44.3147731773466, 6.38315486686481, 100.303757097094, 9.13921010739697, 7.83817900918309, 31.5458855316741, 1.09960505333834, 0.817751834425678, 101.110814846224, 145.55847538105, 142.82362305075, 7.61732986965459, 4.6774198307473, 67.5821464371521)
)

best_dist <- function(x) {
  output <- df$m_1 * x[1] + df$m_2 * x[2] + df$m_3 * x[3] + 
    df$m_4 * x[4] + df$m_5 * x[5] + df$m_6 * x[6]
  mean(abs(output - df$real))
}

restriction <- function(x) sum(x) - 1

nloptr(
  x0 = rep(1 / 6, 6), 
  eval_f = best_dist, 
  lb = rep(0, 6), 
  ub = rep(1, 6), 
  eval_g_eq = restriction, 
  opts = list(algorithm = "NLOPT_GN_ISRES", xtol_rel = 1e-16, maxeval = 1e4)
)
```

As you could read I'm using the `nloptr` package. The above code yields the not optimal result of 14.85 for the objective function and the parameters are all the inital parameters. You may change the initial parameters to some other vector and still won't get the optimal solution.

However, using the excel solver one can easily get a result of **10.77** for the objective function and **(0, 0, .15, 0, 0, .85)** for the parameters.

I've tried using an algorithm with gradient, however I can't seem to get the syntax right. Here's my other attempt.

```
gradient <- function(x) {
  output <- df$m_1 * x[1] + df$m_2 * x[2] + df$m_3 * x[3] + 
    df$m_4 * x[4] + df$m_5 * x[5] + df$m_6 * x[6]
  err <- output - df$real

  c(
    - sum(sign(err) * df$m_1), 
    - sum(sign(err) * df$m_2), 
    - sum(sign(err) * df$m_3), 
    - sum(sign(err) * df$m_4), 
    - sum(sign(err) * df$m_5), 
    - sum(sign(err) * df$m_6)
  )
}

nloptr(
  x0 = runif(6), 
  eval_f = best_dist, 
  eval_grad_f = gradient, 
  lb = rep(0, 6), 
  ub = rep(1, 6), 
  eval_g_eq = restriction, 
  opts = list(algorithm = "NLOPT_GN_ISRES", xtol_rel = 1e-16, maxeval = 1e4)
)
```

Comment: You are solving this as an NLP. A better way would be to observe that minimizing the mean is the same as minimizing the sum. With this you can state the problem as an LP (linear programming) problem. This will give you global optimal solutions. (The abs needs a standard reformulation).

Comment: But the mean is a linear operator, it's just a linear combination where each variable is multiplied by 1/n. The reason this is an NLP problem is the absolute value, which cannot be expressed as a linear combination. How can I standardize the abs formulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is like **LAD Regression** with a side constraint. LP (linear programming) formulations for LAD regression are shown [here](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/11/lp-and-lad-regression.html). Using your naming of the data (real[i], m[i,j]), we have:

```
min sum(i, | real[i] - sum(j,m[i,j]*x[j]) |  ) 
subject to
   sum(j, x[j]) = 1
   0 <= x[j] <= 1
```

This can be linearized (using **variable splitting**) as follows:

```
min sum(i, r1[i]+r2[i])
subject to
   r1[i]-r2[i] = real[i] - sum(j,m[i,j]*x[j])
   sum(j, x[j]) = 1
bounds:
   r1[i], r2[i] >= 0       (positive variables)
   0 <= x[j] <= 1
```

This is a pure LP and can be solved with any LP solver.